# xdotool not found while executing script from Java application

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, java, xdotool

I'm trying to execute the `sh` script from Java application using `ProcessBuilder`. The script checks for the browser file-upload window and then select it and then provide new image and submit. The file upload window of browser is automated using the script.

When I try to execute the script from terminal, everything works fine.

But when I execute the same script from Java application using `ProcessBuilder`, I get `/usr/bin/xdotool: No such file or directory`. I tried different ways adding `"/usr/bin/"` to `path` in same script or using absolute paths, also tried running script by calling another script from Java and then from that script I called actual script. I think now I hit the wall. Somehow from Java, I can not access all the power of bash shell.

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/ankit/workspace/test.jpg"
browser="chrome"
win_name="Open File"
echo "Looking for the window of the '$browser' browser with name '$win_name'"
WIN=$(for pid in $(/usr/bin/xdotool search --class "$browser"); do if [[ $(/usr/bin/xdotool getwindowname $pid) == "$win_name" ]]; then echo $pid; fi; done)
/usr/bin/xdotool windowactivate $WIN
/usr/bin/xdotool type "$file"
/usr/bin/xdotool key alt+o
```

**Java Method**

```
private void selectImageFromFileUploadDialog() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/home/ankit/workspace/resource/handle_file_dialog/run.sh");
                pb.inheritIO();
                Process process = pb.start();
                process.waitFor();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

**Update-1:**
I checked the bash mode, it is neither. Not sure if it will help

```
if [[ -o emacs ]]; then
  echo emacs mode
elif [[ -o vi ]]; then
  echo vi mode
else
  echo neither
fi
```